# lock the first value from a groupby in dataframe pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, locking

I want to lock the first value from a groupby in dataframe pandas.

Is that possible?

example:

[image: this is the dataframe]

[image: And this is how i would like to have it]

Hope someone can help me...

Comment: please provide your data as text

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`groupby`+`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html).

If you want to replace by the first value:

```
df['b'] = df.groupby('a')['b'].transform('first')
```

or by the min value:

```
df['b'] = df.groupby('a')['b'].transform('min')
```

output:

```
   a    b
0  1  100
1  1  100
2  1  100
3  2  400
4  2  400
5  2  400
6  3  700
7  3  700
8  3  700
```

Comment: @Tony it would be great that you take the time to update your question with nicely formatted text

Comment: oke i'm gonna do that

Answer (score 0):

This will do it for you

```
kv = df.groupby(by='first_col')['second_col'].first().to_dict()

def helper(k):
    return kv[k]

df['second_col'] = df['first_col'].apply(lambda x: helper(x))
```

Note `first_col` and `second_col` are your column names

Comment: I saw the answer by mozway after I posted mine, that one is more elegant for this usecase. But in my case you can tweak the helper function for rather complex things too. Please accept the other answer :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer!